# How to open a certificate from a smartcard and validate the pin entered by the user

Tags: vb6, activex, chilkat

I am a chilkat registered user.

I am using visual basic 6.

Is possible to open a certificate from a smartcard and validate the pincode entered by the user?

Regards,
Josefh

Comment: To clarify your question - are you asking about integration between VB6 and the Chilkat API? Or are you mainly asking about Chilkat itself? Either way, what have you done so far, and what has/has not worked?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the certificate is installed on the Windows system, and Chilkat will use the smartcard automatically.  Make sure you're using Chilkat v9.5.0.75 or later.  There is a ChilkatCert.SmartCardPin property (introduced in v9.5.0.75) that allows for the PIN to be set by the application to prevent the Windows dialog from appearing.   If you don't set the SmartCardPin property (which is OK), then the 1st access to the private key will cause the Windows OS to popup the smart card PIN dialog.

Comment: I need to validate the PIN that the user informs. How can I do this?

Comment: Matt, How can I do this? Please send me an example!